# Keeping user's input after server-side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to keep the user's input like name, email and address when they submit a form and it fails the validation on the controller and redirects them back to the page. Should I use viewdata to pass the user's input back to the view or is it bad practice? if so, what should I use?

Comment: *is it bad practice* no. If this solves your problem do it. Though you could *argue* a view model **might** be better.

Comment: that sounds like a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...fails the validation on the controller and redirects them back to the page.

You should not redirect on validation failure. Simply return the view again, with the model that was posted:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

This assumes you're following the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern and doing a postback to the same URL. If that's not the case, you should strongly consider refactoring your code in that way.

The only *good* reason to post to a different action that the one that's rendering your form is if the form is part of the layout, or otherwise placed on multiple different views rendered by multiple different actions. If that's the scenario, your best bet is to have a view that contains your form, and return that view, instead of redirecting back to the originating action on validation failure. You can provide a hidden input with a `returnUrl` to persist the user's original URL, and once they successfully submit the form, you can then redirect them back to that.